# Is it worth it to change the name of MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

1. Is it worth it to change the name of MainActivity?
2. If it isn't, then how to I name the Model for this activity? I've heard that it couldn't be just "MainModel", because it has to be the model of smth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I do change the name of the MainActivity to something like LoginActivity, HomeActivity, etc.
Does it worth it?
I don't know but for me it a lot easier to know the role of that activity by his name, so sometimes "MainActivity" I change to something else that's telling me the role of that activity